# RedirectMatch syntax to simplify these entries

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm looking to prune down my redirects when dealing with old sub-folders and possible iterations people are linking to. Right now, I'm doing this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)/old-sub-folder/index.html$ https://www.website.com/new-place/
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)/old-sub-folder/$ https://www.website.com/new-place/
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)/old-sub-folder$ https://www.website.com/new-place/
```

So it's the same page, but if I don't add each version here one will go to a 404 page. Is there a way to combine this into one line?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apache - Regular Expression (Regex)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/glossary.html#regex),

> Apache uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions provided by the [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) library.

This means, you can build a regular expression with the common prefix `/old-sub-folder` and an optional trailing part `(?:/|/index.html)?`, e.g.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)/old-sub-folder(?:/|/index.html)?$ https://www.website.com/new-place/
```

Although, I'm not sure, if this is really an improvement. Having three separate simple regular expressions might be more readable (and maintainable) than one more complex expression.